# How to give sort_by name in where condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have included given code

```
  @operator_selected = Operator.where(:id => selected_operator).map{|opr| opr.name}
```

I want to show operator sort by name. please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
@operator_selected = Operator.where(:id => selected_operator).order(:name).map{|opr| opr.name}
```

Comment: If he's just mapping the name `.pluck(:name)` would be better than `.map{|opr| opr.name}`

Comment: @japed yeah. your right. i just copied the given code without optimization.

Comment: please guide how to show sort by values in hash I have given this in my view 

    <div class='show-operators'>
      Operators: All<%= @operators.count %><%= @operators.values[0..2] %>     
    </div>

Comment: You can you also use a shorter notation: `.map(&:name)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this -

```
@operator_selected = Operator.order(:name).where(id: selected_operator).map(&:name)
```

if you always want the order by name why don't add default scope to order by name or just add a scope to order by name

like

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order(:name)
end
```

and use this:

```
@operator_selected = Operator.where(id: selected_operator).map(&:name)
```

OR

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_name, -> {order(:name)}
end
```

and use this:

```
@operator_selected = Operator.by_name.where(id: selected_operator).map(&:name)
```